# run sipp using tcl command

Tags: tcl

I want to run sipp using tcl code.
Can anybody help me here please??
I am new to tcl coding.I surfed in google but I did not get much help.
The steps are here

1. Open command prompt
2. Go to sipp location in my case `C:\Sipp_3.1`
3. Run this command `sipp 10.232.249.124 -i 192.168.200.2 -sf reg.xml`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimally, you might be looking at this:

```
cd {C:\Sipp_3.1}
exec sipp 10.232.249.124 -i 192.168.200.2 -sf reg.xml
```

Of course, you'd be better off factoring that out a bit with some variable so that the various parameters have names:

```
set workingDirectory {C:\Sipp_3.1}
set IP1 10.232.249.124
set IP2 192.168.200.2
set config reg.xml

cd $workingDirectory
exec sipp $IP1 -i $IP2 -sf $config
```

The names could be better, but I really don't know that much about the sipp program.

Comment: Thanks for you response.It is working fine